# Slack API interactive message menu, select subset of users

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm currently developing an interactive message menu that prompts users to select another user in their Slack group. Following this [guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-menus#menu_team_members) I am able to prompt the user to select one user from the entire list of users in the group.

I would like to know if it's possible to limit the size of the list to n specific users? If not, is it possible to set the order of users or at least shuffle them randomly? I should be able to do this using **data_source: external** but would like to know if this can be achieved more elegantly using **data_source: users**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want to show only a subset of users you have two options.

1. provide the list through an external data
2. create the list on the fly as a "Simple Menu", with the sub-set of
   users, e.g. coming from a request to groups.info with names
   added from users.list.